# Embedding Charts and Tables in Word Documents: Dynamic Content Replacement and Graphic Centering

Tags: r, visualization

I'm looking for a way to insert charts and tables into a Word document that already has headers and titles in place. My plan is to replace specific words within the document, such as "Graph1" and "Table1," with the actual charts and tables. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this task effectively.

"Note: The code is functional; however, the charts are not centered on the page."

```
###########
# My Code #
###########

# Path to save the file
Directory <- "C:/Path/To/Your/Directory" # Replace with the desired directory

# Loading the Word document template
document_word <- read_docx("C:/Path/To/Your/Template/Doc1.docx")

# Sample data for the table
table_data <- data.frame(
Name = c("Sartre", "Camus", "Kierkegaard"),
Birth_Year = c(1905, 1913, 1813),
Main_Works = c("Being and Nothingness", "The Stranger", "Fear and Trembling")
)

# Sample data for the plot
data <- data.frame(
Philosopher = c("Sartre", "Camus", "Kierkegaard"),
Influence_Score = c(9, 7, 6)
)

# Create a bar chart using ggplot2
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Philosopher, y = Influence_Score, fill = Philosopher)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
theme_minimal()

# Use cursor_reach to find and position the cursor before adding the image
document_word <- cursor_reach(document_word, "Graph1") |>

# Move the cursor forward to the desired location
cursor_forward() |>

# Add the plot to the document with central location
body_add_gg(value = plot, height = 4, width = 6, pos = "on") |>

# Define the image location for central alignment
ph_location(left = 1, top = 1, width = 6, height = 4, newlabel = "Graph1")

# Save the modified document
output_docx <- paste0(Directory, "/document.docx")
print(document_word, target = output_docx)

# Open the Word document
system(sprintf('start winword "%s"', output_docx))
```